# openvpn usage: how to modify ip address and how to remove a tun interface?

Tags: linux, openvpn

I used openvpn to create a tun interface on linux

```
openvpn --mktun --dev tun2
ip link set tun2 up
ip addr add 10.0.0.2/24 dev tun2
```

now I want to modify the ip address to 10.0.0.1/16, how to do it?
besides, how to remove `tun2`

thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you want to remove an ip address simply use `del` instead of `add.

So `ip addr del 10.0.0.2/24 dev tun2` to remove an IP.  But since you want to remove the interface that doesn't really matter.

To remove an tun* interface simply use ip link del name or in your case `ip link delete tun2`.

Comment: Additionally, if you want it to stay deleted after reboot, use `openvpn --rmtun --dev tun2`.

Comment: I ran this because the interface's IP wasn't updating, and now I get "read from TUN/TAP : File descriptor in bad state (code=77)" on OpenVPN logs. However, it's working, despite this error.